# [[5~^ error on ubuntu 16.04 shutdown

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, shutdown

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot with Windows 10.

I was having the flickering screen problem but I have partially solved it (sometimes it flickers) by following [this previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics).

However the issue I am facing now is that on clicking shutdown, although it does shuts down, before the Ubuntu logo is displayed this particular screen appears

[image]

As you can see, it prints multiple lines of:

```
[[5~^[[5~^[[5~^...
```

I haven't found anything regarding this type of error in the Internet.So can anyone describe what cause of this error is, and how to fix it?

Comment: Bad keyboard, keyboard connection, keyboard cable. Repeated "ESC [ 5 -" strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was occurring because of my faulty keyboard.The Page Up button of my laptop keyboard was getting pressed automatically and continued to do so until I pressed the Page Down button.I don't know the name of the representation type,where Page Down is represented using `[[6~^` and Page Up using `[[5~^`.If anyone knows what it is ,kindly add that in the comment section. 
Further If you want to check whether any key in your keyboard is faulty or not,you can check here [Keyboard Check](http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html)

Comment: Is there any solution if it is happening due to the faulty keyboard of my laptop (without changing the keyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but mine displays `~*[[3`.  In order to prevent this, I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> multiple times from the moment the system is booted (after pressing the power button).  This stops the `~*[[3`'s from appearing.

Sometimes if you press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> while the machine is booting, it will take you into the BIOS or similar settings.  If this happens to you, just press <kbd>ESC</kbd> as soon as Ubuntu starts to load.

Comment: I generally press Ctrl+Alt+F1 which ultimately takes me to the login screen.The thing is that I wanted to know why this happens.

Comment: Is there any solution if it is happening due to the faulty keyboard of my laptop (without changing the keyboard)?