# Message ^3[[^~ and Blinking Screen

Tags: lubuntu

A message like this `^3[[^~` shows when i turn on my laptop, the message still show up even in terminal. When i want to install app using command sudo apt install, error message with these `^3[[^~` shown up.

Can Anyone give me a solution how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Similar but no answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/857037/5-error-on-ubuntu-16-04-shutdown

Comment: What graphics card are you using? What graphics driver are you using? Please edit the question with the answers.

Comment: Looks like you've got a jammed key on your keyboard, or a defective keyboard. If this is not a laptop, unplug your keyboard and see if the problem goes away. Otherwise, look closely at your keyboard for a jammed key.

Comment: Rinzwind : i think its nvidia, but im not sure. I am using acer aspire ES 11

Comment: @heynnema : yeah, its my keyboard broken. the DELETE key always pressed, i check it with keyboard tester in lubuntu live CD/USB instalation. But, now my laptop dont want running an OS anymore. When i turn on my laptop, in screen there's a message : error grub bootloader. Do u think this is kernel problem or what? i am newbie. and I dont know how to fixed my broken keyboard, i try to search on google how fixed it, but the answer dont solve my problem. do u have some tips or solution for me?

Comment: It sounds like my answer about the keyboard WAS correct, and replacing the keyboard WOULD solve the problem. You've got a new problem/symptom now. It's possible that the keyboard is ALSO the cause. Unplug the keyboard and see if it all works.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

Looks like you've got a jammed key on your keyboard, or a defective keyboard. If this is not a laptop, unplug your keyboard and see if the problem goes away. Otherwise, look closely at your keyboard for a jammed key.

response: yeah, its my keyboard broken. the DELETE key always pressed